# Point on $z = \frac{1}{xy}$ closest to origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Where $x>0$ and $y>0$.

I want to work with the square of the distance formula from the origin, so I went with $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 + \frac{1}{(xy)^2}$.

Then I found the first partial derivatives:

$f_x = 2x - \frac{2}{x^3y^2}$ and $f_y = 2y - \frac{2}{y^3x^2}$.

Set them equal to $0$ to find the critical points, and multiply both sides by respective $x$ and $y$ to get a common term to set equal to each other:

$2xy = \frac{2}{x^3y}$ and $2xy = \frac{2}{y^3x}$ so $\frac{2}{x^3y} = \frac{2}{y^3x}$. Simplfying, we get $y^2 = x^2$, or $y = x$ since we are given that $x>0$ and $y>0$.

I'm not sure what to do from here.

Comment: And then $2xy=2/(x^3y)$ shows that $2x^2=2/x^4$ hence $x=y=$ $____$.

Comment: @Did Oh, $x = y = 1$. So the point on the surface closest to the origin is $(1,1,1)$?

Comment: Yes, indeed it is.

Comment: An alternative way would be to apply the AM-GM inequality to x^2, y^2, z^2.

Comment: @Martin How do you apply AM-GM here? I've never heard of it before so I just looked it up and I can't see how it can be used here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The surface you are describing can be described as $xyz = 1$.  Since this is symmetric in $x$ versus $y$ versus $z$, any point where $|x| = |y| = |z|$ would be an extremum in distance from the origin.  Visually, we can see that that such points are minima.

Therefore the solutions must be $x,y,z = (1,1,1), (1,-1,-1), (-1,1,-1),$ or $(-1,-1,1)$.  Only one of these has $x,y > 0$.

Comment: What does "symmetric in..." mean? And how do you know this implies $|x| = |y| = |z|$ as extremums?

Comment: If you switch $x$, with $y$, or $z$, the surface remains the same.  This symmetry implies the surface must be symmetric around the point where all three are equal, or in other words, the surface is perpendicular to the line where $x = y= z$.  Thus, it is an extremum.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution: The [Inequality of arithmetic and geometric means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) 
(with $n=3$) states that for non-negative real numbers $a, b, c$

$$
      \frac{a + b + c}3 \ge (abc)^{1/3}
$$

with equality if and only if $a=b=c$. It follows that if $(x, y, z)$ is a point
on the surface $z = 1/(xy)$ then

$$
     \frac{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}3 \ge (x^2y^2z^2)^{1/3} = 1
$$

and therefore $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 >= 3$ with equality if and only if $x=y=z$ ($= 1$).